# Remove chinese parentheses and inside content in string column with Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

I would like to remove chinese type parentheses and their contents inside from the following dataframe:

```
   id                      title
0   1  【第一次拍卖】深圳市光明新区公明街道中心区（拍卖）   ---> （拍卖）need to remove
1   2      【第一次拍卖】深圳市龙岗区龙岗街道新生社区
2   3   【第一次拍卖】（破）广东省深圳市龙岗区布吉新区       ---> (破) need to remove
3   4      【第一次拍卖】深圳市宝安区新安街道新城大道
4   5    （拍卖）【第二次拍卖】深圳市盐田区沙头角东和路      ---> (拍卖) need to remove
```

I tried with `df['title'].str.replace(r'\（[^（）]*\）', '')` and `df['title'].str.replace(r'\（[^)]*\）', '')`, but they both can remove them if they are in the end of string.

```
0       【第一次拍卖】深圳市光明新区公明街道中心区    ---> this row works
1       【第一次拍卖】深圳市龙岗区龙岗街道新生社区
2    【第一次拍卖】(拍卖)广东省深圳市龙岗区布吉新区
3       【第一次拍卖】深圳市宝安区新安街道新城大道
4     (拍卖)【第二次拍卖】深圳市盐田区沙头角东和路
```

How could I modify my code to get the following output? Thank you.

```
0       【第一次拍卖】深圳市光明新区公明街道中心区 
1       【第一次拍卖】深圳市龙岗区龙岗街道新生社区
2       【第一次拍卖】广东省深圳市龙岗区布吉新区
3       【第一次拍卖】深圳市宝安区新安街道新城大道
4       【第二次拍卖】深圳市盐田区沙头角东和路
```

Comment: The one on 3rd row is not a Chinese type parentheses, that's why your regex didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following three solutions work out:

```
df['title'].str.replace(r'\（[^（）]*\）', '')
df['title'].str.replace(r'\（[^)]*\）', '')
df['title'].str.replace(r'\（\S+\）', '')
```

Out:

```
0    【第一次拍卖】深圳市光明新区公明街道中心区
1    【第一次拍卖】深圳市龙岗区龙岗街道新生社区
2     【第一次拍卖】广东省深圳市龙岗区布吉新区
3    【第一次拍卖】深圳市宝安区新安街道新城大道
4      【第二次拍卖】深圳市盐田区沙头角东和路
```